# How to avoid incrementation of text boxes?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on("click",".btnnn",function()
  {
    $.each(data1,function(_,item)
    {
      if(nam==item.Name)
       {
          $.each(item.PhoneNo,function()
          {
           var text="<br><input type='text' class='append'><button class='btnn'>-</button>";
           $(".btnn").after(text);
           return false;
          });
          return false;
       }
    } 
});
```

When iam clicking a button the text box with button is appending when i click again the display of text boxes are incrementing.I dont understand why it is.As we click the values will be go to initial position but still why the incrementation of texbox for each click is done.
I tried by using above code.But it does not work.Can anyone help me

Comment: Please add `JS Fiddle` of your code so we can understand properly what your actual problem?

Comment: *"display of text boxes are incrementing"*, what do you mean by *incrementing*? In the code it seems that you are adding several `input` element on each click for each `item.PhoneNo`.

Answer (score 0):

You Have To use html() method instead of after() method because html() method is replace a new html with the old html, but after() method doesn`t replace a new html to a old html, it`s added a new html with old html, so you can use html() method for this isseu..

change --

```
$(".btnn").after(text);
```

To --

```
$(".btnn").html(text);
```